# deep clone a List of object in c#

Tags: c#

I have a C# class called "SmallClass".

I have an existing list myList containing objects of type "SmallClass"

I want a deep clone of the list "myList". That is, deep Clone the containing list and deep clone the objects contained in the list.

How should I do this.

```
    public class SmallClass: ICloneable {

    public string str1;
    public string str2;
    public string str3;

     public SmallClass Clone() //This just deep clones 1 object of type "SmallClass"
            {
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
                b.Serialize(m, this);
                m.Position = 0;
                return (SRO)b.Deserialize(m);
            }

      public override equals(Object a)
        {
                return Object.Equals(this.str1 && a.str1);
            }
    }

    public class AnotherClass
    {
           SomeCode();
           List<SmallClass> myList = new List<SmallList>();  //myList is initialized.


           // NOW I want to deep clone myList. deep Clone the containing list and deep clone the objects contained in the list.

         List<SmallClass> newList = new List<SmallClass>();
      foreach(var item in myList)
        {
           newList.Add((SmallClass)item.Clone());
        }
```

}

Comment: What's going on here? `return (a.boolean1 && a.boolean1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Warning**: The `BinaryFormatter` type is dangerous when used with untrusted input. Whilst the usage below should be safe, Microsoft [recommend avoiding `BinaryFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) altogether due to its potential for misuse, and will [remove it from .NET 7–8](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md). Consider using another serializer or approach for your deep clones.

First off, you can define a utility method for deep-cloning any object (root):

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

If you want to deep-clone `myList`, all you need to do is pass it as parameter to the method above:

```
List<SmallClass> myListClone = DeepClone(myList);
```

The most important consideration you need to pay attention to is that all your classes must be marked as serializable, typically through the `[SerializableAttribute]`.

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class SmallClass
{
    // …
}
```

Comment: the ICloneable interface class the interface method "Clone" - so if i were to inherit from ICloneable - I will call the method "Clone" instead of DeepClone()

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` would take care of deep-cloning your entire object graph, without requiring you to stay calling the `Clone` methods progressively. The only constraint is that your custom classes must be marked as `[SerializableAttribute]`.

Comment: Do you mean that just calling "DeepClone(myList)" will automatically take care of deep copying any nested object references in myList?

Comment: This solution is now considered insecure and should not be used for any productive work.
https://aka.ms/binaryformatter

Comment: @Exitare: The security vulnerabilities don't apply to this solution, since we're serializing and immediately deserializing data within the same method, so the deserializer is only receiving trusted input.

Comment: The page specifically covers that too. I just wanted to point out this security advice.

Comment: @Exitare: I've read the page and can't find any advice related to this specific scenario. Could you please paste the relevant part?

Comment: The BinaryFormatter type is dangerous and is not recommended for data processing. Applications should stop using BinaryFormatter as soon as possible, even if they believe the data they're processing to be trustworthy. BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure.

Comment: @Exitare: That's the generic advice. The article also states: "The safe input case is true in some rare circumstances." In the absence of contrary arguments, I believe the above code to be one of those rare exceptions, since the data being serialized and deserialized will definitely not be crossing a trust boundary.

Comment: Ok. Not arguing against that.  Shouldn't we still point out this important fact, because people most of the time just copy/paste stuff from SO into their code. So we could at least provide this small advice?

Comment: @Exitare: Fair point. I've added a warning to the top of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your SmallClass needs to implement the [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable) interface.  Then copy every element using the Clone() method.

```
List<SmallClass> newList = new List<SmallClass>();
foreach(var item in myList)
{
    newList.Add((SmallClass)item.Clone());
}
```

Comment: Will I need to provide a new implementation for the implementation of clone inherited from ICloneable in "SmallClass"

Comment: Yes, ICloneable is just an interface, which means that it has no implementation whatsoever.  You have to implement the Clone() method yourself.  That is what I mean when I say "Implement the interface."

Comment: Ok. I add your suggestion to my original post. Does the code seem to lack anything functionally? SmallClass does not contain class members I will not need to think about cloning these.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of creating a deep copy which include serialization and using Object.MemberwiseClone Method (). Since an example of using serialization is already available here, I have an approach with using "MemberwiseClone".

NOTES: Recursive, Platform: .NETStandard2.0

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a deep copy of an object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T DeepClone<T>(this T source) where T : class
        {
            if(source == null) return null;

            if(source is ICollection<object> col)
            {
                return (T)DeepCloneCollection(col);
            }
            else if(source is IDictionary dict)
            {
                return (T)DeepCloneDictionary(dict);
            }

            MethodInfo method = typeof(object).GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            T clone = (T)method.Invoke(source, null);

            foreach(FieldInfo field in source.GetType().GetRuntimeFields())
            {
                if(field.IsStatic) continue;
                if(field.FieldType.GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive) continue;

                object sourceValue = field.GetValue(source);
                field.SetValue(clone, DeepClone(sourceValue));
            }

            return clone;
        }

        private static ICollection<object> DeepCloneCollection(ICollection<object> col)
        {
            object[] arry = (object[])Activator.CreateInstance(col.GetType(), new object[] { col.Count });

            for(int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
            {
                object orig = col.ElementAt(i);
                object cln = DeepClone(orig);

                arry[i] = cln;
            }

            return arry;
        }

        private static IDictionary DeepCloneDictionary(IDictionary dict)
        {
            IDictionary clone = (IDictionary)Activator.CreateInstance(dict.GetType());

            foreach(object pair in dict)
            {
                object key = pair.GetValueOf("Key");
                object original = pair.GetValueOf("Value");

                clone.Add(key, original.DeepClone());
            }

            return clone;
        }

        public static dynamic GetValueOf<T>(this T value, string property)
        {
            PropertyInfo p = value.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetProperty(property);

            if(p != null && p.CanRead)
            {
                dynamic val = p.GetValue(value);

                return val;
            }

            return Activator.CreateInstance(p.PropertyType); //Property does not have  value, return default
        }
```